# Como escrever códigos como exemplo, sem executar?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu to fazendo a tradução de um livro para uma página HTML, ai no livro tem os códigos, mas como eu faço para o meu HTML exibir o meu código, HTML, PHP e JavaScript, sem executa-los?

Comment: Onde você está fazendo esse texto? HTML puro? Algum framework para blogs como wordpress, por exemplo?

Comment: Aqui tem um site para ajudar a modificar o html para texto: http://blogcrowds.com/resources/parse_html.php

Comment: Caso use jQuery pode fazer isso `$('pre').text( $('pre').html() );`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você precisa escapar os caracteres que fazem suas tags serem interpretadas como HTML, o `<` e o `>`.

Por exemplo, em vez de:

```
<div>Teste</div>
```

use:

```
&lt;div&gt;Teste&lt;/div&gt;
```

Se está usando PHP, existe uma função que faz isso, a [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
echo htmlentities('<div>Teste</div>');
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/DEZduB</sup>

No caso de código PHP, basta dar saída dele sem o `<?php` inicial, e ele não será interpretado. Caso queira incluir o `<?php` no exemplo, use `&lt;?php`.

Comment: Eu pensei em indicar algum plugin que mostre códigos, tipo esse: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/

Comment: Isso mesmo dessa forma funciona super bem. Eu utilizo o plugin Highligth.js para exibir os códigos porém ele executa com as tags < > <?, mas com &lt &gt &lt? ele não executa e mostra o código. Obrigado (:

Comment: Caso use jQuery pode fazer isso `$('pre').text( $('pre').html() );`

Comment: eu também posso fazer assim: &ltli>. Alterar o primeiro "<" que o navegador não irá renderizar, fica bem mais rápido (:.

Comment: KaduAmaral - isso irá escrever o que tá dentro da tag <pre> como código html, sem executar?

Comment: Sim @EstácioDiFabio, o jQuery irá pegar o html `$('pre').html()` e transformar em texto `$('pre').text()`. A tag `pre`, respeita "tudo" que estiver dentro dela, no caso os espaços em branco (não precisa usar `&nbsp;`) e quebras de linhas (não precisa usar `<br>`).

Answer (score 14):

Voce pode usar

```
<xmp>
  <p>Blah teste</p>
</xmp>
```

A tag xmp não precisa usar caracteres de escape.
 O resultado será:

```
<p>Blah teste</p>
```

Comment: Interessante isso, eu não conhecia. Porém encontrei documentação dizendo que [é um recurso obsoleto que pode ser removido dos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp).

Comment: Sim, pode ser descontinuada no futuro, mas por enquanto é a solução mais simples. Um pena ser obsoleto. =)

Comment: Não é a solução mais simples o próprio site fala pra usar <pre> ou <code>

Comment: eu dava +1 mas com esses comentários não dá. Também não conhecia.

Comment: essa é uma ótima técnica, mas dentro das tags <pre> <code> <xmp> <p> olar mundo </p> </xmp> </pre> </code>. O navegador renderiza todo o código por trás dos <pre> e <code>. Mas se for somente para HTML puro funciona super bem. Uma pena mesmo ser obsoleto.

Comment: <pre> ou <code> não funcionam neste caso @AdirKuhn

Comment: @RenaroSantos saquei, mas mesmo obsoleto é uma ótima dica, também não conhecia (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar a tag `pre` e jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('pre').each(function(index, el){
     $(this).text( $(this).html() );
   });
});
```

```css
pre{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

pre.php::before{
  content: '<?php';
  display:block;
  margin:0 0 2px -3px;
}
pre.php::after{
  content: '?>';
  display:block;
  margin:2px 0 0 -3px;
}

hr{margin 7px 0; border-color: #999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
   <p>
      Teste da tag 
      <strong>pre</strong>
   </p>
</pre>
<hr>
<pre class="php">
   $var = 'Hello World!';
   
   if (1 == 1)
     echo $var;
</pre>
```

Porém no caso do PHP, caso também esteja utilizando-o no lado do servidor, terá omitir a tag de abertura `<?php` (pode fazer a emissão dela por CSS).

Answer (score -3):

Eu cai aqui primeiramente por que tinha a mesma duvida "como exibir php na página sem executar".
Acabou que eu não gostei das soluções propostas aqui e fui fazendo testes por conta própria e a solução não poderia ser mais simples.
Basta apenas dar um 'ECHO' no conteúdo PHP que quer exibir, exemplo:

```html
<?php 
  echo "
    <?php 
      function teste(valor) {
        alert(valor);
      }
      //Chamando a função 
      teste('Deu certo');
    ?>
  ";
?>
```

Espero que seja útil, abraços